# Jump and Run: If Player.Bottom collides with Monster.Top, Monster disappears

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a Jump and Run in Windows Forms -Just a simple one.
I got a PictureBox for the Player-Model and another PictureBox for a Monster. If the Player jumps on Top of the Monster, the Monster should disappear and if the Player touches the right or left side of the monster, the Player should disappear.

I already thought about the Bounds-Method, but then whenever the Player touches the Monster, the monster disappears.

```
if (Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Monster.Bounds)) {Monster.Hide();}
```

Comment: :( ... That's all you give use :( ?? But anyways, check [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/537081/how-to-make-the-player-stay-within-screen-in-a-sim.html) out for some knowledge :)

Comment: You are only checking if the rectangles intersect.  You haven't applied any of your logic for left-right or top.  Hint: create smaller rectangles from the bounds to test for your varied conditions.

Comment: @LarsTech and how do i create some smaller rectangles from the bounds? Im kinda new to Programming, sorry

Comment: Something like `var r = new Rectangle(Monster.Bounds.Left, Monster.Bounds.Top, 4, Monster.Bounds.Height);`  That would give you a rectangle for the left side of the Monster.  You would have to decide what to do with the Top-Left corner, since your specs have two different things happening there.